# Asked my code to read the first line in an external file but it doesnt work but when I asked for the second line it work

Tags: python

```
def login():
    drug = True
    while True:
        username = input("Enter your username: ")
        password = input("Enter your password: ")
        for row in open("user.txt", "r"):
            data = row.split(",")
            print(data[0],data[1])
            if username == data[0].strip() and password == data[1]:
                print("Welcome to Music Quiz.")
                return username

        else:
            print("no")

login()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHrV1.png)

The user file has
m,l
s,l

For some reason, when I entered username: m and password: l it doesn't work and respond with a 'no' but when I enter s,l it work.

Or if I remove s,l from the user file, and then enter m,l it works fine.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Take a look at the indentation , the else should be at the same level with the if

Comment: `print(repr(data))` and see what you are actually reading. I bet that `row` ends with a newline character, so you need to `.rstrip('\n')` before comparing to the password.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; we need your question to be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: Your posted code hangs waiting for input -- don't expect us to enter test data, or to build a test file.
Instead, simply hard-code a test case that causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of accomplishing your task. Basically I've split the combinations and paired them into groups. For example data will be equal to.
`[['m', 'l'], ['s', 'l']]` because those are the password and username combinations. Then the user will enter their own pwd and usr and we will check if that combination can be matched in `data`.

---

```
import re
def login():
    drug = True
    while True:
        username = input("Enter your username: ")
        password = input("Enter your password: ")
        for row in open("user.txt", "r"):
            #split the row so that it looks like this ['m', 'l', 's', 'l']
            #other wise it would look like this ['m', 'l s', 'l']
            data = re.split(",| ",row)
            #this pairs the list into groups of two.
            x = [data[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(data), 2)] 
            #check if the user's pwd and usr combo is equal to the files comb
            for combinations in x:
                if [username,password] == combinations:
                    print("Welcome to Music Quiz.")
                    return username
            else:print("no")

login()
```

Also a major problem you had is, yes you split the data at the comma but you also had to split the data at the space or the data would look weird.
So in order to do that this code uses regex in order to split a string at multiple delimeters.

---

**our output (s,l)**

```
Enter your username: s 
Enter your password: l
Welcome to Music Quiz.
```

**our output (m,l)**

```
Enter your username: m
Enter your password: l
Welcome to Music Quiz.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following.You are not splitting correctly.

```
def login():
    drug = True
    while True:
        username = input("Enter your username: ")
        password = input("Enter your password: ")
        with open("user.txt", 'r') as f:
            for row in f.readlines():
                data_list = row.split(" ")   #Correction here
                data = data_list[0].split(",")
                print(data[0],data[1])
                if username == data[0].strip() and password == data[1]:
                    print("Welcome to Music Quiz.")
                    return username

                else:
                    print("no")

login()
```

Note: I have made the program perfect for the first case of m and l that you have asked for. However, with correct splitting, you can make the program perfect for the other cases too.